# How to dual boot Black Box Linux with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual boot Black Box 3 along with Ubuntu 12.04.

How do I go about achieving the same?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Back Box is a linux distribution, you will not actually be installing it "in" Ubuntu but rather it would be installed as a dual boot O/S.

This http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2180011 shows how to do similarly with Scientific Linux and Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  The principles will be the same.  You will need to make space for the new distribution, install it and update your Grub to "see" Back Box.  And, better yet, here is a mini-how-to on the [Back Box forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20130721015633/http://forum.backbox.org/general-support/how-to-install-backbox-3-01-alongside-ubuntu-12-04-lts-and-windows-xp).

Another possibility is to install the tools that exist in Back Box on to your Ubuntu installation.  This will save you from installing another O/S just to get forensic tools,  for example, which may be in Ubuntu's repository now.

There are many links about how to install multiple boot setups using different distributions of Linux.